# Ansible playbook “path specified in src not found”

Tags: ansible, juniper

I am runnning into this message when I do this :

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory junos_config_new.yml --check -vvv
```

> ansible-playbook 2.9.9 config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
>   configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules',
>   '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules'] ansible python module location =
>   /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible executable location =
>   /usr/bin/ansible-playbook python version = 3.6.8 (default, Nov 21
>   2019, 19:31:34) [GCC 8.3.1 20190507 (Red Hat 8.3.1-4)] Using
>   /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file host_list declined parsing
>   /home/gefela/ansible_junos/inventory as it did not pass its
>   verify_file() method script declined parsing
>   /home/gefela/ansible_junos/inventory as it did not pass its
>   verify_file() method auto declined parsing
>   /home/gefela/ansible_junos/inventory as it did not pass its
>   verify_file() method Parsed /home/gefela/ansible_junos/inventory
>   inventory source with ini plugin

PLAYBOOK: junos_config_new.yml ***************************************************************************************************************************** 1 plays in junos_config_new.yml

This is the playbook that I have ...

```
    name: Juniper SRX configuration compliance checks 
    hosts: juniper
    gather_facts: false
    connection: local
       tasks:
         - name: Syslog server checks 
           junos_config:
                 src: ~/ansible_junos/files/syslog_config.txt
             comment: Ensure that appropriate Syslog server configured 
           register: junos_output
         - debug:
             var: junos_output

         - name: success
             debug:
               msg: Syslog server check - This check has passed with the following output({{ junos_output }})
               when: not junos_output.changed 

         - name: failed
            debug:
              msg: Syslog server check - This check has failed with the following output({{ junos_output }})
             when: junos_output.changed 

         - name: Admin credentials check
            junos_config:
                   src: ~/ansible_junos/files/admin_user.txt
               comment: Ensure that Admin user havee been created
            register: junos_output
         - debug:
              var: junos_output

         - name: success
               debug:
                 msg: Admin credentials check - This check has passed with the following output({{ junos_output }})
                when: not junos_output.changed 

         - name: failed
              debug:
                msg: Admin credentials check - This check has failed with the following output({{ junos_output }})
               when: junos_output.changed
```

The directory ~/ansible_junos/files/syslog_config.txt is in the right place
Should ~/ansible_junos/files/ be the right place to place all the configuration to be compared against the firewall ?

Please let me know ..

Answer (score 1):

It's because `~` is a bash feature, and not an actual path component; your *shell* expands `~` to mean the home directory for the current user (or for the user named directly after the `~`), however, ansible modules would have to go out of their way to use [`expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to behave like that.

You can try sending the filename through the [`| expanduser` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8), or you may have to use `gather_facts: true` in order to have access to `ansible_env.HOME`

```yaml
     - set_fact:
         config_directory: '{{ "~/ansible_junos/files" | expanduser }}'
     - name: Syslog server checks 
       junos_config:
         src: '{{ config_directory }}/syslog_config.txt'
         comment: Ensure that appropriate Syslog server configured 
       register: junos_output
```

Comment: [root@localhost ansible_junos]# ansible-playbook -i inventory junos_config_new.yml --check -vvv


task path: /home/gefela/ansible_junos/junos_config_new.yml:10
fatal: [172.16.203.121]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "path specified in src not found"
}

172.16.203.121             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Comment: - set_fact:   
      config_directory: '{{ "home/gefela/ansible_junos/files" | expanduser }}'
  - name: Syslog server check
    junos_config:
      src: 'home/gefela/files/syslog_config.txt'
      comment: Ensure that appropriate Syslog server configured 
    register: junos_output

Answer (score 0):

src jues need "admin_user.txt"

```
    - name: Admin credentials check
        junos_config:
               src: "admin_user.txt"
           comment: Ensure that Admin user havee been created
        register: junos_output
```

add  you can add admin_user.txt  in files/admin_user.txt

Comment: It is still give me the same error message when I add src: "syslog.txt". When I make it 

 junos_config:
         src: '{{ config_directory }}/syslog_config.txt' 
It gives me the error message 

"module_stdout": "\n{\"msg\": \"FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')\",  

I have tried all these , no success yet

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the inventory file ( ansible_user and ansible_password ) and change this

- set_fact:
  config_directory: '{{ "~/ansible_junos/files" | expanduser }}'

  - name: Syslog server checks
    junos_config:
    src: '{{ config_directory }}/syslog_config.txt'
    comment: Ensure that appropriate Syslog server configured
    register: junos_output

to

- set_fact:
  config_directory: '{{ "/home/myfolder/ansible_junos/files" }}'

  - name: Syslog server checks
    junos_config:
    src: '{{ config_directory }}/syslog_config.txt'
    comment: Ensure that appropriate Syslog server configured
    register: junos_output